# iPhone device orientation problem

Tags: iphone, orientation, device

My application is Navigation based.

All views are displaying Portrait mode except Report mode.Report mode display landscape mode when device is rotate landscape.

If device is rotate landscape mode Report view is displaying landscape mode.if report is landscape mode once again rotate in device Portrait mode it will display normal view of current view.

Flow of current action my view display.
From current view is Portrait mode and i am rotating device in landscape mode so getting Landscape mode of Report mode. after two rotate only i am getting current view in Portrait mode. I need to reduce tow rotation . please guide me . How to check condition for after landscape mode of Report if once again rotate i need to display current view in Portrait mode.

```
Here at ReportViewController 


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);

}

@interface CurrentViewController

BOOL isShowingLandscapeView;
Report *landscapeViewController;

@implementation CurrentViewController 


- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Report *viewController = [[Report alloc]initWithNibName:@"Report" bundle:nil];
    self.landscapeViewController = viewController;
    [viewController release];

    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{

    [self performSelector:@selector(updateLandscapeView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
}


- (void)updateLandscapeView
{
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) && !isShowingLandscapeView)
    {   

        [self presentModalViewController:self.landscapeViewController animated:YES];
        isShowingLandscapeView = YES;

    }
    else if(deviceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait && isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    }    
}



- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ); // support only portrait

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but the code looks like it might have the logic reversed.
 In the ReportViewController,

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation
```

is called before the rotation, so it should
    return YES for Portrait (YES, allow the view to rotate from Landscape TO portrait)
and return NO  for Landscape (NO, do not allow the view to rotate to Landscape from Landscape).

And similarly in CurrentVC - try

```
return (interfaceOriention==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape);
```

Hope that helps.
-Mike

Comment: It is not possible to return (interfaceOriention==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape);There is no check condition for UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape. Only possible left or right and Islandscape.
updateLandscapeView  method When i check Portrait mode 
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation) && !isShowingLandscapeView)
current view as Portrait and rotate device it is Current view as landscape and rotate, report view is landscape and rotate Current view as  Portrait.I need Current view is Portrait if rotate device report view is landscape and rotate current view is Portrait.